# cordova error in sendsms() for multiple numbers ,"Message Failed:error"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

In cordova as has been sad in [github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/8](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/8) we can use multiple numbers but i have this error,

```
sendSms2: function (id) {
    try {
        var number = "'"+window.localStorage.getItem("NUMBERS") + "'";
        var message = window.localStorage.getItem("TEXT");
        alert(number + " : " + message);
        console.log("number=" + number + ", message= " + message);
        //CONFIGURATION
        var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: ''
            }
        };
        var success = function () {
            alert('Message sent successfully for:' + id);
        };
        var error = function (e) {
            alert('Message Failed:' + e);
        };
        sms.send('9133333333,9122222222', message, options, success, error);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
},
```

but i get "Message Failed:error" in alert,

It works for one, but not for more,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible,

use for loop

```
sendSms2: function (id) {
    try {
        var busyFlag = 0;
        if (!busyFlag) {
            var number = '9133333333,9122222222';
            var numbers = number.split(",");
            var message = 'test';
            alert(number + " : " + message);
            //CONFIGURATION
            var options = {
                replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
                android: {
                    intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
                }
            };
            var success = function () {
                alert('Message sent successfully for:' + id);
            };
            var error = function (e) {
                alert('Message Failed:' + e);
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                busyFlag = 1;
                sms.send(numbers[i], message, options, success, error);
            }
            busyFlag = 0;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```